# (Python) How to take a variable from a message on discord using discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am writing a simple discord bot for fun, and i want it to take (for example) a number from a message after certain phrase and use it later
for example a certain user types "$test 6" and i want my bot to take that number ( 6 ) and for another example send it to the same channel.

i came up after creating this question to split the message.content
will it work? (not counting that the user could write something else than numbers)

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("$test"):
        stringOne = str(message.content)
        stringTwo = "$test "
        split = stringOne.partition(stringTwo)[2]
        await message.channel.send("number/s from your message: " + split)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with command arguments:

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, number = None):
    if not number:
        await ctx.send("Please enter a number, for example: `$test 5`")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Here's the number you gave me: {number}")
```

And an example using some discord objects:

```py
@bot.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, *, reason = "Default reason"):
    if not member:
        await ctx.send("Please provide a member for me to kick!")
    else:
        await member.kick(reason=reason)
        await ctx.send(f"Successfully kicked {member} for `{reason}`")
```

---

**References:**

- [f-Strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) - Python 3.6.0+
- [`*` usage in parameters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-do-my-arguments-require-quotes)
- [`commands.Command()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.command) - The decorator for creating/registering commands to your bot.
- [`commands.Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) - This will always be passed as the first parameter in a command.
- [`Context.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.send) - `Context` inherits from `abc.Messageable`, meaning that you can send a message to the channel that the command was executed in.
- [`abc.Messageable`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable)
- [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member)
- [`Member.kick()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.kick)